# Changing TabBarController & NavigationController when using MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to change the the colour of a navigation bar controller and also a tab bar controller

I am using the monotouch.dialog to build my application and have the following code

```
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;

    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // If you have defined a view, add it here:
        // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);
        CreateTabs();
        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }

    protected void CreateTabs()
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var nav = new UITabBarController ();
    nav.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {
        new HomeController("Home"),
        new WhereToUseController(),
        new TransactionsController(),
        new SettingsController()
    };

    //  nav.TabBarController.TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    nav.CustomizableViewControllers = new UIViewController [0];
    window.RootViewController = nav;
// window.BackgroundColor =  UIColor.Orange;        
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    }
```

An example of one of my controllers

```
    public override void LoadView ()
    {
        base.LoadView ();
    //TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
  //  ParentViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    }

    public HomeController (string s)
    {

         TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem (s, null, 1);

        var root = new RootElement (s) {


            new Section () {
                new UIViewElement("My Caption:", view, false),
                new StyledStringElement("Hello","somevalue"),
                new StringElement ("Welcome back Shane"),
                    new ImageElement(new UIImage("Images/QR.png")),
            }
        };

        PushViewController (new DialogViewController (root), false);
    }
```

Where am I meant to be changing the colour? to allow me to change the top and bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target iOS 5 (and more recent versions) then you should look at the new `UIAppearance` feature. It will allow you to set the look of all types of control for your application (once, not for each that you create).

E.g. calling this

```
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
 UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Green;
```

from your `FinishedLaunching` will make all navigation bar with a black background, even those from MonoTouch.Dialog (instead of the default blue) and the tab bar with a green background (instead of black).

**note 1:** before iOS5 you'll need to set the `*Color` properties for each control (which is less fun since you don't always have access to them).

**note 2:** you're creatine  a new instance of `UIWindow` two times, i.e. the following is called in `FinishedLaunching` and `CreateTabs`

```
  window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
```